# Displaying blog feed on personal website

Tags: blogger

I created a blog post http://rexonms.blogspot.com/ and want to incorporate it with a website I am creating.

When never I post a new blog, I want the heading to show up on my new site. Is there a script or tool that I can use to get the desired functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you're looking for is an aggregator or scraper to use the RSS feed from your blogspot site and output it elsewhere (namely, your website). You might start here: http://www.rssinclude.com/ and see if it gives you the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Problematic!! thanks for the URL. That pretty much what I am looking for except I just want the title of each blog not the whole thing. And it the site doesn't offer that feature. Probably for good for next project. 
Thanks,
Rex